# Is there any possibility to access pictures on my S10 which always freezes on startup

Tags: backup, data-recovery

My S10 always freezes on startup, because of an update. It just doesn’t reach the end of the loading bar. I know I could wipe the data via recovery, but I want the pictures back at least.

Comment: Have you tried booting into [safe mode](/tags/safe-mode/info)?

Answer (score 1):

You can go into safe mode in one of two ways.

1. Press and hold the **Power** button until you see the Power Off icon.
2. Press and hold the **Power Off** icon until you see the Safe Mode icon.
3. Press on the **Safe Mode** icon

OR

I can not verify the 2nd method right now as I don't have an S10, but the above is simpler anyway.

1. Press and hold the **Power** button until you see the Samsung Galaxy Logo Screen.
2. Release the **Power** button.
3. While the logo is still visible, press and hold the **Volume Down** button until you see the Safe Mode indicator.

**To exit Safe Mode, press on the Power button and restart the phone.**

Answer (score 1):

Well after a lot of research on Friday I can say more about it now.

The phone booted into download mode all the time. The only thing which helped was to install home csc. After that it worked perfectly fine again.

Thanks for all your answers :)